# Adding text to textbox from a button that supports multiple lines without erasing

Tags: vb.net

So basically what I want to do is click a button and this will put my text into a textbox and add ?xml=1 after it. If someone wants to help me with the entire thing the image is below of what I want it to do

Here is what I mean https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eatj.png

Heres what it looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCoJ0.png but everytime I click ?xml=1 it adds to the bottom this doesnt matter on which line I click it'll just add it to the end

What I am using for the ?xml=1 part is TextBox1.Text &= "?xml=1"
{Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    TextBox1.Text &= "?xml=1"
End Sub
```

End Class}

Comment: Heres what happens when I click the ?xml=1 http://i.stack.imgur.com/PTlmq.png also this is vb if you havent guessed it yet

Comment: You need to actually show the code you're using. Copy and paste it into your question using the [edit] link. To format it correctly, select the entire code block and click the button in the edit toolbar with the curly braces: `{}`

Comment: I havent done much like I said before

Answer (score 1):

Your form is incomplete, various pieces of information is needed to generate the Steam64Id number.

Namely, you will need the "Universe", "AccountType", "AccountInstance" and off course "Account Number".

When you put the component values values together into the whole, you end up with the Steam64Id number.

You can see how it breaks down in the image below.

[image: Breakdown of Steam64Id number]

Further information can be found on the steam developers pages

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID

## Update

If the textbox you enter the account number in is called txtSource and your entered 0123456789 as the number and the textbox you want to write it into after adding "?xml=1" is called txtDestination then the code to transfer it over is

```
txtDestination.text = txtSource.text & "?xml=1"
```

and if you want to transfer it over whilst adding the URL then it would be

```
txtDestination.text = "http://steamcommunity.com/ID/" & txtSource.text & "?xml=1"
```

or

```
txtDestination.text = "http://steamcommunity.com/PROFILES/" & txtSource.text & "?xml=1"
```

There are still some unresolved issues in so much as you have not clarified whether it is an ID or a profile so when you rewrite it as a URL would it be http://steamcommunity.com/ID/0123456789?xml=1 or would it be http://steamcommunity.com/PROFILES/0123456789?xml=1 my guess is that only one is right and the other is wrong.

Once you have got the correct folder wether its ID or Profiles a successful call will return an XML document and you must extract the data from that.

## Update II

Well I had some free time today so I managed to knock out this code, it goes with the image further down, I didn't have time to do the web page scraping bit, but i'm sure there will lots of examples on SO of where other users have asked similar questions. Hope this is enough to set you on your way.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim Reference As Long

  If Trim(TextBox1.Text) <> "" Then
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
      Reference = Shell("c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/" & Trim(TextBox1.Text) & "?xml=1")
    Else
      Reference = Shell("c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe http://steamcommunity.com/id/" & Trim(TextBox1.Text) & "?xml=1")
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox("No steam Id entered!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
  End If

End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

  If Trim(TextBox2.Text) <> "" Then
    TextBox3.Text = "http://steamcommunity/friends/add/" & TextBox2.Text
  Else
    MsgBox("No steam 64 Id specified!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
  End If

End Sub


Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

Dim Reference As Long

  If Trim(TextBox3.Text) <> "" Then
    Reference = Shell("c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe " & Trim(TextBox3.Text))
  Else
    MsgBox("No steam 64 Id specified!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
  End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: If you add any community profile page and add ?xml=1 at the end you will be prompted to a page with the steamid64. I would just need to scrape that and format it to steam://friends/add/steamid64goeshere then from here just httprequest which will launch steam and do the rest on its own do you understand what I am trying to do?